# connect-function (winsock2.h) doesn't find Host

Tags: c++, windows, client, c++20, winsock2

I'm currently trying to understand how to establish a server-client connection under Windows using the header file "winsock2.h". I have done the "Getting started" from Microsoft ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/winsock/getting-started-with-winsock)) and now I have a problem that I can't solve!
The problem is that my program returns at the function [connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-connect) SOCKET_ERROR (WSAGetLastError == 11001 == WSAHOST_NOT_FOUND) (with "www.google.com").
So I looked up what kind of website was suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo#example-code) and then tried this too ([www.contoso.com](http://www.contoso.com)), with the same result
I would be very grateful if someone could explain the problem to me!

```
constexpr auto DEFAULT_PORT   = "27015";
constexpr auto DEFAULT_BUFLEN = 512;

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>

...

WSADATA   wsa_data;
SOCKET    sock;
addrinfo* result = NULL;
addrinfo* ptr = NULL;
addrinfo  hints{};
PCSTR     port = DEFAULT_PORT;

WSAStartup(WINSOCK_VERSION, &wsa_data)

ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

// Resolve the server address and port
getaddrinfo(host_name, port, &hints, &result)

for (ptr = result; ptr != nullptr; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {

    sock = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);

    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cout << "\nERROR: socket failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanUp();
        return WSAGetLastError();
    }

    if (connect(sock, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(sock);
        sock = INVALID_SOCKET;
        continue;
    }

    break;
}

freeaddrinfo(result);

if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    std::cout << "\nERROR: unable to connect to server!\n";
    WSACleanUp();
    return WSAGetLastError();
}

WSACleanUp();
```

EDIT: forgot to copy the initialize of the port variable

Comment: There is no error handling being done on `getaddrinfo()`. Also, your use of `WSAGetLastError()` is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You have the following line defining the `port` variable on the stack:

```cpp
PCSTR     port;
```

However, you have not initialized, or later set, the value to anything before using it in your `getaddrinfo` call:

```cpp
getaddrinfo(host_name, port, &hints, &result)
```

This parameter is, according to [getaddrinfo function (ws2tcpip.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo),

> [in, optional] pServiceName
>
> A pointer to a NULL-terminated ANSI string that contains either a service name or port number represented as a string.

Since the value is most likely not NULL, the function would try to read from an arbitrary part of memory. This results in no valid service name or port number being found, thus causing it to not be able to find the host.

Comment: I'm sorry... I forgot to copy this over, bc I wanted to simplify my project and not share 5 Files of code.